Using SWRLAPI with OWLAPI v5?
Is there a way to create SWRL rules with OWLAPI 5 ? For now, I'm using SWRL 2.1.2 with OWLAPI 4.5.29. But I now face dependency problems with owlexplanation, so a solution may be to switch to OWLAPI 5. But what about my code using SWRLAPI ?
Is there a SWRLAPI version compatible with OWALAPI 5 ? How to translate my code to create SWRL rules in order to not use SWRLAPI anymore ?
Thank you for your help ;-)
Regards,
Manuel

SWRLApi is a protege library, and protégé still uses OWLAPI 4, so probably no. And we cannot suggest how to change your code if you don't show it. Can you share the code, either in the question or with a pointer to a repository?

Hi. Here is a very short code I'm using: SWRLRuleEngine ruleEngine = SWRLAPIFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(ontology);
ruleEngine.createSWRLRule("R1", "Person(?p)^hasAge(?p,?age)^swrlb:greaterThan(?age,17) -> Adult(?p)");
